# T-SQL Override special rates and generate final date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, gaps-and-islands

I have transaction table which has date range and basic rate for the range. I have another table for special rate which has date range for special rate and its rate. I would like to split my original transaction in multiple records if special rates falls in transaction date range.

Just for simplicity I have created two tables with limited columns

```
DECLARE @ClientTrx AS TABLE (ClientId int, StartDate Date, EndDate Date, Rate decimal(10,2))
DECLARE @SpecialRate AS TABLE (ClientId int, StartDate Date, EndDate Date, Rate decimal(10,2))

insert into @ClientTrx select 1, '1/1/2020', '1/15/2020', 10
insert into @ClientTrx select 1, '1/16/2020', '1/31/2020', 10
insert into @ClientTrx select 2, '1/1/2020', '1/15/2020', 20
insert into @ClientTrx select 2, '1/16/2020', '1/31/2020', 20
insert into @ClientTrx select 2, '2/1/2020', '2/13/2020', 20

insert into @SpecialRate select 1, '12/25/2019', '1/3/2020', 13
insert into @SpecialRate select 1, '1/4/2020', '1/6/2020', 15
insert into @SpecialRate select 1, '1/11/2020', '1/18/2020', 12

insert into @SpecialRate select 2, '1/25/2020', '1/31/2020', 23
insert into @SpecialRate select 2, '2/4/2020', '2/8/2020', 25
insert into @SpecialRate select 2, '2/11/2020', '2/29/2020', 22
```

I need help write a query which produce following results:

```
ClientId    StartDate   EndDate Rate
1   2020-01-01  2020-01-03  13.00   special rate
1   2020-01-04  2020-01-06  15.00   special rate
1   2020-01-07  2020-01-10  10.00   regular rate
1   2020-01-11  2020-01-15  12.00   special rate
1   2020-01-16  2020-01-18  12.00   special rate splitting pay period
1   2020-01-19  2020-01-31  10.00   regular rate
2   2020-01-01  2020-01-15  20.00   regular rate  
2   2020-01-16  2020-01-24  20.00   regular rate
2   2020-01-25  2020-01-31  23.00   special rate
2   2020-02-01  2020-02-03  20.00   regular rate  
2   2020-02-04  2020-02-08  25.00   special rate
2   2020-02-09  2020-02-10  20.00   regular rate 
2   2020-02-11  2020-02-13  22.00   special rate
```

I think using CTE its possible but I can't figure it out. can anyone please help?

Note: I have made some changes in my input and expected output, i think I need one more group level, can you please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an approach which uses and ad-hoc tally table to expand the datasets and then applies a Gaps-and-Islands for the final summary

**Example**

```
;with cte as (
Select A.ClientId
      ,D    
      ,Rate = coalesce(NewRate,A.Rate)
      ,Grp  = datediff(day,'1900-01-01',D) - row_number() over (partition by ClientID,coalesce(NewRate,A.Rate) Order by D)
 From  @ClientTrx A
 Cross Apply ( 
                Select Top (DateDiff(DAY,StartDate,EndDate)+1) D=DateAdd(DAY,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),StartDate) 
                 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2 
             ) B
 Outer Apply (
               Select NewRate=Rate 
                 From @SpecialRate
                 Where D between StartDate and EndDate
                   and ClientId=A.ClientID
             ) C
)
Select ClientID
      ,StartDate= min(D)
      ,EndDate  = max(D)
      ,Rate     = Rate
 From  cte
 Group By ClientID,Grp,Rate
 Order by ClientID,min(D)
```

**Returns**

```
ClientID    StartDate   EndDate     Rate
1           2020-01-01  2020-01-03  13.00
1           2020-01-04  2020-01-06  15.00
1           2020-01-07  2020-01-10  10.00
1           2020-01-11  2020-01-18  12.00
1           2020-01-19  2020-01-31  10.00
2           2020-01-01  2020-01-24  20.00
2           2020-01-25  2020-01-31  23.00
2           2020-02-01  2020-02-03  20.00
2           2020-02-04  2020-02-08  25.00
2           2020-02-09  2020-02-10  20.00
2           2020-02-11  2020-02-15  22.00
```

Notes:

Cross Apply B generates a record for each date between startDate and endDate in @ClientTrx.

Outer Apply C attempts to find the Exception or NewRate

the CTE generates one record per date and toggles the default or exception rate.  It looks like this

[image]

Notice how GRP changes.   This is a simple technique to "feed" the Gaps-and-Islands

Then is becomes a small matter to group the results from cte by ClientID and Grp

Comment: I could not understand fully but it gives me what I needed. Can you please explain role of master..spt_values?